# Проблема с чатом на workerman+wss (websockets)

Tags: ssl, https, chat, workerman, websokets

Я делаю чат на вебсокетах с ***ssl*** при помощи библиотеки ***workerman***. У меня возникла проблема. Борюсь с ней уже довольно долго. Где и что я только не гуглил, но решил-таки просто задать вопрос.

Проблема в том, что в официальной документации [***workerman***](https://github.com/walkor/Workerman) дан код, на основе которого я построил свой wss сервер. Все было хорошо, пока я не понял, что он просто возвращает сообщение, отправленное клиентом, обратно. А мне нужно, чтобы он разослал его всем подключениям.

Код моего wss сервера ниже.

```
<?php
    require_once ('../vendor/autoload.php');
    use Workerman\Worker;

    // SSL context.
    $context = array(
        'ssl' => array(
          'local_cert'=> 'путь.crt',
            'local_pk' => 'путь.key',
           'verify_peer'  => false,
        )
    );


    // Create a Websocket server with ssl context.
    $ws_worker = new Worker("websocket://0.0.0.0:8080", $context);


    // Enable SSL. WebSocket+SSL means that Secure WebSocket (wss://). 
    // The similar approaches for Https etc.
    $ws_worker->transport = 'ssl';

    // Emitted when new connection come
    $ws_worker->onConnect = function($connections)
    {
        echo "New connection\n";

    };

    $ws_worker->onMessage = function($connection, $data)
    {
        // Send hello $data
        $data = json_decode($data);
        $date = date("H:i");
        $messageArray = [
            'user' => $data->chat_user,
            'lvl' => $data->chat_lvl,
            'message' => $data->chat_message,
            'date' => $date
            ];

            // отправляем сообщение
            $connection->send(json_encode($messageArray));
    };
    // Emitted when connection closed
    $ws_worker->onClose = function($connection)
    {
        echo "Connection closed\n";
    };

    Worker::runAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

Я нашел решение:

```
    $ws_worker->onMessage = function($connection, $data) use ($ws_worker){

    $data = json_decode($data);
    $date = date("H:i");
    $messageArray = [
        'user' => $data->chat_user,
        'lvl' => $data->chat_lvl,
        'message' => $data->chat_message,
        'date' => $date
    ];

    // отправляем сообщение
    foreach ($ws_worker->connections as $connect) {
       $connect->send(json_encode($messageArray));
    }
};
```